# Awk/Gsub alternative for special characters and string extraction

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a file containing many lines such as below:

```
<li><img src="img/tt_potato-30x30.png" alt="ew_inactive"> <img src="img/in-event-40x40.png" alt="event"> - dep[(0:0)(0:0)]ref[(3:0)(0:0)]srch[?] - <a href "tcc_1111.html">XX:The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy  </a>  -<img src= "img/config-40x40.png" alt="config"><img src="img/validate-40x50.png"  alt="validate"> - user

<li><img src="img/tt_potato-30x30.png" alt="ew_inactive"> <img src="img/in-event-40x40.png" alt="event"> - dep[(0:0)(0:0)]ref[(3:0)(0:0)]srch[?] - <a href "tcc_1111.html">YY:Jack and Jill went up the hill  </a>  -<img src= "img/config-40x40.png" alt="config"><img src="img/validate-40x50.png"  alt="validate"> - user

<li><img src="img/tt_potato-30x30.png" alt="ew_inactive"> <img src="img/in-event-40x40.png" alt="event"> - dep[(0:0)(0:0)]ref[(3:0)(0:0)]srch[?] - <a href "tcc_1111.html">ZZ: Mary had a little lamb  </a>  -<img src= "img/config-40x40.png" alt="config"><img src="img/validate-40x50.png"  alt="validate"> - user
```

I wish to extract the following strings and discard the everything else.

```
XX: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy
YY: Jack and Jill went up the hill
ZZ: Mary had a little lamb
```

So far I've tried using the following awk command but it appears to be limited as the XX needs to be replaced for YY and ZZ.

```
awk '{gsub(/^.*XX:/,"XX:"); gsub(/[<\a>].*$/,"[</a>].");print}'
```

Is there an alternative anyone can suggest using any other standard Linux tool?
Thanks.

Comment: How generic does XX/YY/ZZ need to be?   You could just do `[XYZ]{2}` in most regex engines if that's it.

Comment: @stevesliva, I think the problem is more (or also) that OP has to vary the replacement string as well depending on which letters are matched in the regex.

Comment: Hi, Jas is correct,variation in replacing the string before the ' : '  would be a requirement.. Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^.XX` means `any character followed by XX at the start of a line` - it will not match `XX` mid-line. `[<\a>]` means `any of the characters <, \, a, or >` - it will not match the string `<\a>`. Find a regexp tutorial...

Your question isn't clear but maybe this is what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk '{sub(/<\/a>.*/,""); sub(/.*>/,"")} NF' file
XX:The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy
YY:Jack and Jill went up the hill
ZZ: Mary had a little lamb
```

or with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() to print whatever's between ... (assuming one per line):

```
$ awk 'match($0,/.*<a[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>.*/,a){print a[1]}' file
XX:The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy
YY:Jack and Jill went up the hill
ZZ: Mary had a little lamb
```

which in any sed would be:

```
$ sed -n 's/.*<a[^>]*>\(.*\)<\/a>.*/\1/p' file
XX:The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy
YY:Jack and Jill went up the hill
ZZ: Mary had a little lamb
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Input_file is same as shown example then following may help you in same too.

```
awk -F"\">|</a>" 'NF{print $4}'  Input_file
```

**Explanation:** Making `">` and `</a>` as a field separator(obviously to get what OP needs :) ). NF will make sure we should skip empty lines. Now when we set field separator as these 2, we could see 4th field will be the one which OP requires, here is how we could see all the field's value and we could pick 4th column which OP needs to get.

```
awk -F"\">|</a>" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print i,$i}}'  Input_file
1 <li><img src="img/tt_potato-30x30.png" alt="ew_inactive
2  <img src="img/in-event-40x40.png" alt="event
3  - dep[(0:0)(0:0)]ref[(3:0)(0:0)]srch[?] - <a href "tcc_1111.html
4 XX:The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy
5   -<img src= "img/config-40x40.png" alt="config
6 <img src="img/validate-40x50.png"  alt="validate
7  - user
1 <li><img src="img/tt_potato-30x30.png" alt="ew_inactive
2  <img src="img/in-event-40x40.png" alt="event
3  - dep[(0:0)(0:0)]ref[(3:0)(0:0)]srch[?] - <a href "tcc_1111.html
4 YY:Jack and Jill went up the hill
5   -<img src= "img/config-40x40.png" alt="config
6 <img src="img/validate-40x50.png"  alt="validate
7  - user
1 <li><img src="img/tt_potato-30x30.png" alt="ew_inactive
2  <img src="img/in-event-40x40.png" alt="event
3  - dep[(0:0)(0:0)]ref[(3:0)(0:0)]srch[?] - <a href "tcc_1111.html
4 ZZ: Mary had a little lamb
5   -<img src= "img/config-40x40.png" alt="config
6 <img src="img/validate-40x50.png"  alt="validate
7  - user
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: In shell you should use single quotes around strings, etc. unless you NEED double quotes (e.g. to let a variable expand). If you follow that rule then it has the nice side benefit that in this case you don't need to escape the double quote when you set FS, i.e. instead of `-F"\">|</a>"` you should write `-F'">|</a>'`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this perl one-liner would do (looks like you are on linux):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if m{>((XX|YY|ZZ):[^<]*)}'
```

Comment: Thanks for all the replies will try them all and leave an update. Much appreciated